# Indy TIdTcpServer input buffer empty

Tags: delphi, indy

I have an application that listens for a tcp client connection. When the client connects, the client sends over a large chunk of data, in one example 100+k. The Indy TCPServer receives it, processes/reformats the data, sends it on to an http server in the cloud, receives a response, creates an acknowledgement based on the response, and sends it back to the client, disconnecting the connection.

```
procedure TMyApp.TCPConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  try
    AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadTimeout := 10000;
  except
    on E:Exception do
      AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyApp.TCPDisconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  SetLength(FMDMStr,0);
end;

function TMyApp.TransferTCPBytesToString(AnIOHandler: TIdIOHandler): String;
begin
  if AnIOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
    Exit;
  Result := AnIOHandler.WaitFor(#28#13,True,True);
  if Pos(#28#13,Result) = 0 then
    Result := Result + #28#13;
end;

procedure TMyApp.WriteTCPResponse(AnIOHandler: TIdIOHandler);
var
  bytes: TIdBytes;
begin
  BuildACK(FMDMStr,bytes);
  AnIOHandler.WriteDirect(bytes, Length(bytes));
end;

procedure TMyApp.TCPExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  try
    FMDMStr := TransferTCPBytesToString(AContext.Connection.IOHandler);
    // test string for HL/7 terminating characters
    if Pos(#28#13, FMDMStr) > 0 then
    begin
      FormatAndSendHTTPMsg(FMDMStr);
      // send the response back to tcp client
      WriteTCPResponse(AContext.Connection.IOHandler);
    end;
  except
    on E:Exception do
      AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
  end;
end;
```

I have used this app in varying scenarios for over 2 years and it works well. I've tested it across multiple windows 10 & windows server 2016 SE servers and it works fine.

The most recent deployment isn't working at all; the same client sends across >100k of data, connecting to the TIdTcpServer; the execute method fires, but there is a -0- sized input buffer. I've set the receive buffer to 256k just to be on the safe side. Here's what I'm logging:

```
AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferAsString
AContext.Connection.IOHandler.RecvBufferSize
AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty
```

ReceiveBuffer logs as 262144. InputBufferIsEmpty always comes back true! And of course the InputBufferAsString := ''.

So I'm wondering if this could possibly be a security "feature" on the server/network/domain that the app is running on? I've tested it on two different servers on the domain, exactly the same result. Client connects, logs that it is sending, the IdTcpServer logs the connection, but receives nothing.

Any thoughts or advice will be greatly appreciated! TIA

Comment: What does your server code actually look like? The `InputBuffer` does not fill up with data automatically, your code has to perform reading operations for it to fill up.  Indy doesn't read data from the socket until you ask it to do so. Have you verified with a packet sniffer that data from the client is actually reaching the server?

Comment: Yes; the client logs the data that it is sending. The OnConnect event fires. OnExecute fires in a loop as expected. I have since gotten farther along on this, and am currently experiencing a problem that does not appear to be related to Indy. This has been a really weird episode, as the code worked everywhere tested except for on one particular domain. I've since tweaked the code; am using WaitFor() to get the data from the socket connection, this seems to fit the bill best. Will update as the problems are discovered/resolved.  Thanks!

Comment: "*the client logs the data that it is sending*" - that doesn't mean the data is actually reaching the server. It just means the data is reaching the client's local kernel buffer. "*am using WaitFor() to get the data from the socket connection*" - that would fall under "your code has to perform reading operations for [the InputBuffer] to fill up".

Comment: All issues have been resolved. @RemyLebeau Since the client is pushing data to the server, won't the InputBuffer get filled without action on the part of the TIdTcpServer? Isn't that what the looping OnExecute event is responsible for? Or does the data from the client push get stored somewhere else? Also, is it possible to gather incoming data in the OnConnect event? Or must the OnExecute event be used? In other words, is there a manual process that can be used to collect the data apart from the OnExecute event?  Thanks.

Comment: "*Since the client is pushing data to the server, won't the InputBuffer get filled without action on the part of the TIdTcpServer?*" - no, that is what I said earlier. You have to explicitly tell Indy to perform a read operation. It will then pull the requested bytes from the InputBuffer, reading from the socket as needed and putting new bytes into the InputBuffer, until the read is satisfied. "*Isn't that what the looping OnExecute event is responsible for?*" - no. The loop has no concept of the socket state, it is just a blind loop. The event handler is responsible for the necessary logic

Comment: "*Or does the data from the client push get stored somewhere else?*" - it stays in the socket's internal buffer until you tell Indy to read it out. "*is it possible to gather incoming data in the OnConnect event?*" - yes. The TCP connection is fully established before the `OnConnect` event is fired. For instance, `OnConnect` is a good place for handling initial handshake/login procedures when a client first connects, and then `OnExecute` could be used for the main logic afterwards.

Comment: "All issues have been resolved" - are they really? You never did show your actual code. Without a [mcve], it is hard to say why things were not working for you in the first place.  You say things were fixed when you added `WaitFor()`, that is fine, but sounds like it may be more of a band-aid than a proper solution, depending on what your protocol actually looks like.  I'm still interested in seeing your actual code (both client and server) to make sure you are addressing things *properly*.

Comment: I have added server code for your evaluation. I don't have access to the client code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `try..except` in `TCPConnect()` is useless. Setting the `ReadTimeout` is not going to raise an exception. And in any case, if an uncaught exception escapes the `OnConnect` or `OnExecute` event, the server will disconnect the client automatically.

`FMDMStr` is not being used in a thread-safe manner. Each `TIdContext` runs in its own thread. DO NOT share variables across thread boundaries without proper synchronization.  In this case, if there is only ever 1 client connected (and you enforce that by setting `TIdTCPServer.MaxConnections=1`), then so be it. Otherwise, `FMDMStr` should not be a class member variable at all, it should be a local variable of `TCPExecute()` instead (or alternatively, stored in the `TIdContext`), so that each connected client operates on its own unique `string`.

The `InputBufferIsEmpty` check in `TransferTCPBytesToString()` needs to be removed. Indy does not fill the `InputBuffer` until it is told to perform a read operation, where new bytes need to be pulled from the underlying socket. So the `InputBuffer` will remain empty until something attempts to read from the connection.  If you are always checking for an empty `InputBuffer` first, you can lose the opportunity to read your data.  Let `WaitFor()` block normally until data arrives, or times out.

Also, since you are setting `AInclusive=True`, the return value of `WaitFor()` will always include `#28#13` at the end, so the `Pos()` check is useless and should be removed.  Also, since `TransferTCPBytesToString()` always returns a string with `#28#13` on the end, the `Pos()` check in `TCPExecute()` is useless, too.

In `WriteTCPResponse()`, you SHOULD NOT be using `TIdIOHandler.WriteDirect()` at all.  Use appropriate `TIdIOHandler.Write()` overloads instead.  There is an overload for sending `TIdBytes`.

With that said, try something more like this:

```pascal
procedure TMyApp.TCPConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadTimeout := 10000;
end;

function TMyApp.TransferTCPBytesToString(AnIOHandler: TIdIOHandler): String;
begin
  // will throw an exception on timeout...
  Result := AnIOHandler.WaitFor(#28#13,True,True);

  // alternatively:
  // Result := AnIOHandler.WaitFor(#28#13,True,True,nil,10000);
  // then you don't need to set the IOHandler.ReadTimeout...
end;

procedure TMyApp.WriteTCPResponse(AnIOHandler: TIdIOHandler; const AMsg: string);
var
  bytes: TIdBytes;
begin
  BuildACK(AMsg, bytes);
  AnIOHandler.Write(bytes);
end;

procedure TMyApp.TCPExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  FMDMStr: string;
begin
  FMDMStr := TransferTCPBytesToString(AContext.Connection.IOHandler);
  // TODO: change FormatAndSendHTTPMsg() to return the response string
  // directly, rather than save it in a class member variable...
  FMDMStr := FormatAndSendHTTPMsg(FMDMStr);
  // send the response back to tcp client
  WriteTCPResponse(AContext.Connection.IOHandler, FMDMStr);
end;
```

---

FYI, on a side note, your code mentions HL/7.  Indy has a `TIdHL7` component that can operate in server mode, running an internal `TIdTCPServer` that reads in and responds to HL/7 messages, firing an `OnReceiveMessage` event for each message. In your scenario, you could set `TIdHL7.Port` to your desired listening port, set `TIdHL7.CommunicationMode=cmSynchronous`, set `TIdHL7.isListener=True`, assign a handler to `TIdHL7.OnReceiveMessage` to send your HTTP message, and then call `TIdHL7.Start()` at runtime when ready.

Just something to consider...

Comment: Really appreciate the response. As for the Try..Except in OnConnect, I should have taken that out since I attempted to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), stripping out logging statements etc. That is what the Try...Except block was for, not for the timeout assignment. I'll set the MaxConnections := 1; Interesting on the HL/7 front. I take it that Indy is used a lot for HL/7 interface work?

Comment: Just went into D11 Ent and checked for TIdHL7... here's what I found in IdRegister.pas:
  IdFTPServer,
  IdGopher,
  IdGopherServer,
  IdHashMessageDigest,
  //IdHL7,
  IdHTTP,
  IdHTTPProxyServer,
  IdHTTPServer,
  IdIPAddrMon,.... what's the story? Do I have to download a custom version of Indy? I'm updated with both patches for D11... There are also many references to RSHL7... in IdResourceStringsProtocols.pas, including  ...\Studio\22.0\source\Indy10\Protocols\IdResourceStringsProtocols.pas(831):   RSHL7Broken                  = 'IdHL7 is broken in Indy 10 for the present';

Comment: "*I take it that Indy is used a lot for HL/7 interface work?*" - I don't know. I just know that the component exists, but I've never used it myself, or heard of anyone else using it, but it has a fairly involved implementation so someone put some work into it.

Comment: "*`RSHL7Broken = 'IdHL7 is broken in Indy 10 for the present';`*" - interesting, I wasn't aware of that. I don't know why that is the case. Maybe it was written during the Indy 8/9 timeframe and was never reviewed/updated for Indy 10.  I don't know.  It compiles, but hasn't been touched in years. I guess you could always remove that error message and then try the component and see what actually happens. You don't need it registered in the IDE to use it, you can instantiate it in code at runtime, eg: `var IdHL7 := TIdHL7.Create(Owner); IdHL7.Port := ...; ... IdHL7.Start;`

Comment: My concern is that my search for 'HL7' in the source directory didn't turn up an 'IdHL7.pas' file, just the two aforementioned files. It doesn't appear to be present in the source folder.. On another note, I incorporated some of your changes, and actually only use the OnConnect event, even for follow-on processing. I set MaxConnections :=1, changed WriteDirect to Write, dumped the explicit timeout call, replaced with AnIOHandler.WaitFor(#28#13,True,True,nil,10000); OnExecute is assigned, but contains no code.  I am able to chalk this up to "simpler is better"

Comment: "*my search for 'HL7' in the source directory didn't turn up an 'IdHL7.pas' file*" - Really? It is present in Indy's repo: [`/Lib/Protocols/IdHL7.pas`](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/blob/master/Lib/Protocols/IdHL7.pas)

Comment: "...Original author Grahame Grieve..." cool! We've worked with him before. I'll save out the file from the link and test it for a future release. Thanks again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240219/discussion-between-decoder-and-remy-lebeau).